# In R, a column of my dataframe is populated with other dataframes. I want to return a specific value as a new column in the original dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I downloaded a data set from the web. It's got 6 columns, and the 6th column is filled with other dataframes. So, an example:

```
id          homeTeam    homeScore  awayTeam     away    stats
401112436   Louisville  17         Notre Dame   35      <data.frame [4 × 4]>
401112114   Oklahoma    49         Houston      31      <data.frame [4 × 4]>
401114218   USC         31         Fresno State 23      <data.frame [4 × 4]>
```

I want to create a new column in the original dataframe with the value in row 1, column 2 of the "stats" dataframe for each row.

I added a row_id column with the row number, and tried

```
df$new_col <- df$stats[[df$row_id]][1,2]
```

but I'm getting a recursive error. When I hard code a number

```
df$stats[[1]][1,2]
```

it returns the correct number. I don't know why it wouldn't work with the row_id value just the same.

Comment: Try using single brackets for row selection, `df$stats[1][1,2]`, does that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `pluck` from `purrr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>% mutate(new_col = map_dbl(stats, pluck, 2, 1))
```

Using a reproducible example :

```
temp <- data.frame(a = 1:4, b = 2:5)
df <- tibble(a = 1:2, b = 6:7, c = list(temp, temp))

df %>% mutate(new_col = map_dbl(c, purrr::pluck, 2, 1))

#      a     b c                new_col
#  <int> <int> <list>             <dbl>
#1     1     6 <df[,2] [4 × 2]>       2
#2     2     7 <df[,2] [4 × 2]>       2
```

Answer (score 0):

With `map`, we loop over the 'stats' column, extract the second column, first element to create the 'new_col' in `mutate` and `unnest` the `list` element

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df <- df %>%
         mutate(new_col = map(stats, ~  .x[[2]][1])) %>%
         unnest(c(new_col))

df
# A tibble: 2 x 4
#      a     b stats            new_col
#  <int> <int> <list>             <int>
#1     1     6 <df[,2] [4 × 2]>       2
#2     2     7 <df[,2] [4 × 2]>       2
```

If the column is `character`, use `map_chr`, if it is `double`, use `map_dbl` or if we don't know the type, then simply use `map` to return a `list` column and then `unnest`

---

Or in `base R`

```
df$new_col <- sapply(df$stats, function(x) x[[2]][1])
```

#### data

```
temp <- data.frame(a = 1:4, b = 2:5)
df <- tibble(a = 1:2, b = 6:7, stats = list(temp, temp))
```

Comment: For both of your solutions, I'm getting the same error... "Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : subscript out of bounds"

Comment: @ragsy12 it is a bit disappointing when both my methods are working